# Creating temporary resource test files in Scala

Tags: scala, io

I am currently writing tests for a function that takes file paths and loads a dataset from them. I am not able to change the function. To test it currently I am creating files for each run of the test function. I am worried that simply making files and then deleting them is a bad practice. Is there a better way to create temporary test files in Scala?

```
import java.io.{File, PrintWriter}

val testFile = new File("src/main/resources/temp.txt" )
val pw = new PrintWriter(testFile)

val testLines = List("this is a text line", "this is the next text line")
testLines.foreach(pw.write)
pw.close

// test logic here

testFile.delete()
```

Comment: val testFile = File.createTempFile() ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would generally prefer `java.nio` over `java.io`. You can create a temporary file like so:

```
import java.nio.file.Files
Files.createTempFile()
```

You can delete it using `Files.delete`. To ensure that the file is deleted even in the case of an error, you should put the `delete` call into a `finally` block.

Comment: import java.nio.file.Files